# Add an image to a windows workflow custom activity designer

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I am developing some custom activities in Windows workflow using the designer to add some nice custom looks for users. I have been able to do everything like in WPF mostly although I am having an issue loading images in the actual workflow view. This is how it looks in the designer

[image]

```
<sap:ActivityDesigner.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Collapsed">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="40"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image MaxWidth="40" MaxHeight="20" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="pack://application:,,,/Images/Web.ico"></Image>
            <Label VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1">Collapsed View</Label>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Expanded">
     <Grid>
    <Label>hi</Label>
    </Grid>

    </DataTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="ExpandOrCollapsedStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource Collapsed}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ShowExpanded}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource Expanded}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</sap:ActivityDesigner.Resources>
 <Grid>
    <ContentPresenter Style="{DynamicResource ExpandOrCollapsedStyle}" Content="{Binding}" />
</Grid>
</sap:ActivityDesigner>
```

But in Visual Studio 2015 when creating a workflow, it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-workflow-foundation/how-to-create-a-custom-activity-designer?

Comment: @Alex C, Yes I have..

Comment: My initial instinct is that the designer cant find the image, but i've tried setting the image properties as Resource and Embedded Resource, and i tried removing "pack" and just having /Images/Web.ico

Comment: I don't know what could be going wrong, for me it would be "hammer time", debugging VS or something :) But I'm sure someone with more experience in WF and custom designers can offer better advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I've found is that the image needs to include the namespace.  The image tag should look similar to this:

```
<Image MaxWidth="40" MaxHeight="20" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
       Source="pack://application:,,,/MyNamespace;component/Lookup.png"></Image>
```

The Build Action for the Lookup.png should be "Resource".

Comment: So did you try this and it worked? I can't get it to work... maybe I'm doing something wrong. I tried Souce="pack://application:,,,/MyNamespace;component/Lookup.png" and i tried swapping out component with Images as it is in a folder called Images and swapped out MyNamespace with my actual namespace!

Comment: It worked thank you!, I did: Source="pack://application:,,,/MyNamespace;component/Images/Lookup.png"></Image>